# memcpy was not declared error in eclipse CDT C++

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to do memcpy

```
 char *pdata = data pointer;
 int64_t deviceId;
 memcpy(&deviceId, pdata+1, 8);
```

And it complains "memcpy was not declared in this scope"

I have included below libraries in my header file

```
<stdio.h>
<stdlib.h>
<unistd.h>
```

How do I fix this problem. Thank in advance..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`mempcy` is defined in `string.h`, excerpt from man:

```
 SYNOPSIS
 #include <string.h>

 void *
 memcpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

Answer (score 2):

memcpy is in string.h , so add it

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/